# How many groups of order $512$ and $1024$ are there with a center of size $2$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap

I did not find a sequence in OEIS about the number of groups of a given order with a center of size $2$.

For the first few powers of $2$, the numbers are :

$2$ : $1$ group

$4$ : $0$ groups

$8$ : $2$ groups

$16$ : $3$ groups

$32$ : $10$ groups

$64$ : $27$ groups

$128$ : $121$ groups

$256$ : $605$ groups

I wanted to count the number of groups of order $512$ with a size of center $2$ with GAP, but it takes very long.

The first million of the groups contains $4842$ examples, the next million of groups all have center-size $16$ and the groups from $10,400,000$ to the last group contains $29$ such groups

> Questions : Does anyone know the number of groups of order $n$ with a center of size$2$ for $n=512$ and $1024$ ?
>
> Can the probability that a random group of order $n$ has a center of size $2$ be estimated for higher values ($2048$ or even $4096$) ?

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718461/random-group-of-order-4096-with-a-center-of-size-2?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the data for groups of order $512$ which I calculated using ParGAP package on an 8-core machine for the 2009 paper "The modular isomorphism problem for the groups of order $512$" with Bettina Eick.

For groups of order $512$, I have:

```
gap> Length(centersize);
10494213
gap> Collected(centersize);
[ [ 2, 5327 ], [ 4, 128741 ], [ 8, 4303591 ], [ 16, 6025263 ], 
  [ 32, 30014 ], [ 64, 1063 ], [ 128, 184 ], [ 512, 30 ] ]
```

so the number of groups with the centre of order $2$ is $5327$.

My data agree with your observations:

```
gap> Number([1..10^6],i->centersize[i]=2);
4842
gap> Number([10^6+1 .. 2*10^6],i->centersize[i]=2);
0
gap> ForAll([10^6+1 .. 2*10^6],i->centersize[i]=16);
true
gap> Number([10400000 .. Length(centersize)],i->centersize[i]=2);
29
```

Groups of order 1024 are not included in the GAP Small Groups Library, so this is going to be harder. I don't know if anyone knows.

For even larger groups, to start with, is there a clean definition what does "the random group of order $n$" mean?

Comment: Superb answer. Which package do I need for this ?

Comment: With random group I mean the following : From all groups of the given order upto isomorphism, we pick up a group in such a way that every group has the same chance to be selected.

Comment: I used ParGAP that time, but now for parallel distributed calculations with the current stable GAP release I suggest [SCSCP](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/scscp/doc/chap8.html). Moreover, IIRC you have Windows.

Comment: Of course I've seen it (and even commented there ;-). If you have a list of small groups of a given order, a naive approach is to try `SmallGroup(n,Random[1..NrSmallGroups(n)])`. But those groups are ordered somehow (see `SmallGroupsInformation(n)`), so it's not clear how "random" your choice would be. For groups when you don't know the order, it's even more difficult.

Comment: Your command does exactly what I want. But it only works if the program knows all the groups. For large groups, I would need a method to construct ANY group (I would already be confident if every group could theoretically be constructed by the method). Any ideas ?

Comment: I just noticed that you probably misunderstood me : I want a random group with fixed order, not a random group with unknown order.

Comment: No, I understood that you have fixed order in mind. I don't think it's easy.